# Is there a way to keep track on user's sessions within applications in the same tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, httpsession

I have multiple applications (wars) deployed on same Tomcat application server. Each application has form login and uses Spring Security to authenticate. There is a centralized application (not in same Tomcat) from which Spring Security checks user credentials.

Is there a simple way to keep track on user's sessions in those wars and invalidate user's session within each war in case user logs off from one?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On

Comment: Does the tomcat's "single sign on" work if I am not using Tomcat to manage authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I started using [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/). It integrates with Spring Security and offers a way to store users's sessions to a database.